# Pulling thread data from Invision power board from an external Java application

Tags: java, multithreading, regex

What I am planning on doing is pulling the first post of my news section. This was made for VBulletin and now I need to add it for IPb.

```
package com.rigory.loader.main.services;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import com.rigory.loader.main.gui.MainFrame;
import com.rigory.loader.main.gui.SplashScreen;
import com.rigory.loader.main.services.data.ThreadData;
public class LatestThread {
```

String to VBulletin:

```
private final String WEBSITE_URL ="http://rigory.com/forums/forum/8-news-and-announcements/";
```

Regex search thread name:

```
private final String REGEX_THREAD_NAMES = "<font color=\"#0099FF\"><strong>(.*?)</a> ";
```

Regex search thread URL:

```
private final String REGEX_THREAD_URL = "border=\"0\" /> <a href=\"(.*)\">1</a>";
```

Regex search thread content (this used to be a developer font color in an HTML element, now we have it stored as a CSS element):

> div > div.post_body > div.group_4.post.entry-content > p:nth-child(1)

```
private final String REGEX_THREAD_CONTENT ="<div class=\"blizzquote\">(.*)";
```

This variable is the index of your latest news post:

```
private final int THREADINDEX = 3;

private SplashScreen splash;

public LatestThread(SplashScreen splash){
    this.splash = splash;
}
public List<ThreadData> getData(){
    List<ThreadData> out = new ArrayList<ThreadData>();
    try{
        URL url = new URL(WEBSITE_URL);
        BufferedReader reader =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String inputLine;
        int count = 0;
        while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null  && count < THREADINDEX) {
            ThreadData in = getDetails(inputLine);
            if(in != null){
                out.add(in);
                count++;
                this.splash.getProgressBar().setValue(this.splash.getProgressBar().getValue() + 33);
                this.splash.getDescLbl().setText("Loading News Data.");
                this.splash.repaint();
                this.splash.validate();
            }
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return out;
}
```

Create a new `ThreadData` object from our regex strings. This method should be rewritten, rushed job.

`@param` line - our line from the URL

`@return` new `ThreadData` object

```
    private ThreadData getDetails(String line){
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX_THREAD_NAMES);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
        if(matcher.find()){
              String title = matcher.group(1);
              pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX_THREAD_URL);
              matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
              if(matcher.find()){
                  String urlLink = matcher.group(1);
                    return new ThreadData(title,urlLink,getContent(urlLink)); 
              }
        }
        return null;
    }
    private String getContent(String urlLink){
          String output = null;
          try {
        URL url = new URL(urlLink);
        BufferedReader reader =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
               Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX_THREAD_CONTENT);
               Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputLine);
                while (matcher.find()) {
                    output = matcher.group();
                    output = output.replace("<div class=\"blizzquote\">","");
                    try {
                        output = output.substring(0, output.indexOf("</div>")-1);
                    } catch (Exception e){ }
                }
        }
        reader.close();
          } catch (Exception e){
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
        return output;
    }

}
```

This is the full file:

```
package com.rigory.loader.main.services;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import com.rigory.loader.main.gui.MainFrame;
import com.rigory.loader.main.gui.SplashScreen;
import com.rigory.loader.main.services.data.ThreadData;

public class LatestThread {
    /** String to VBulletin */
    private final String WEBSITE_URL = "http://rigory.com/forums/forum/8-news-and-announcements/";
    /** Regex search Thread Name */
    private final String REGEX_THREAD_NAMES = "<font color=\"#0099FF\"><strong>(.*?)</a> ";
    /** Regex search Thread URL */
    private final String REGEX_THREAD_URL = "border=\"0\" /> <a href=\"(.*)\">1</a>";
    /** Regex search Thread Content */
    private final String REGEX_THREAD_CONTENT ="<div class=\"blizzquote\">(.*)";
    /** This variable is the index of your latest news post **/
    private final int THREADINDEX = 3;

    private SplashScreen splash;

    public LatestThread(SplashScreen splash){
        this.splash = splash;
    }
    public List<ThreadData> getData(){
        List<ThreadData> out = new ArrayList<ThreadData>();
        try{
            URL url = new URL(WEBSITE_URL);
            BufferedReader reader =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            String inputLine;
            int count = 0;
            while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null  && count < THREADINDEX) {
                ThreadData in = getDetails(inputLine);
                if(in != null){
                    out.add(in);
                    count++;
                    this.splash.getProgressBar().setValue(this.splash.getProgressBar().getValue() + 33);
                    this.splash.getDescLbl().setText("Loading News Data.");
                    this.splash.repaint();
                    this.splash.validate();
                }
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return out;
    }
    /** 
     *  Create a new ThreadData Object from our regex strings
     *  This method should be rewritten, rushed job.
     * @param line - our line from the URL
     * @return new ThreadData object
     * 
     */
    private ThreadData getDetails(String line){
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX_THREAD_NAMES);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
        if(matcher.find()){
              String title = matcher.group(1);
              pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX_THREAD_URL);
              matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
              if(matcher.find()){
                  String urlLink = matcher.group(1);
                    return new ThreadData(title,urlLink,getContent(urlLink)); 
              }
        }
        return null;
    }
    private String getContent(String urlLink){
          String output = null;
          try {
        URL url = new URL(urlLink);
        BufferedReader reader =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
               Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX_THREAD_CONTENT);
               Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputLine);
                while (matcher.find()) {
                    output = matcher.group();
                    output = output.replace("<div class=\"blizzquote\">","");
                    try {
                        output = output.substring(0, output.indexOf("</div>")-1);
                    } catch (Exception e){ }
                }
        }
        reader.close();
          } catch (Exception e){
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
        return output;
    }

}
```

This is the ThreadData.java file:

```
package com.rigory.loader.main.services.data;

public class ThreadData {
    private String title;
    private String url;
    private String post;

    public ThreadData(String title, String url, String post) {
        super();
        this.title = title;
        this.url = url;
        this.post = post;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }
    public String getUrl() {
        return this.url;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ThreadData [title=" + title + ", url=" + url + ", post=" + post
                + "]";
    }

    public String getPost() {
        return this.post;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
    public void setPost(String post) {
        this.post = post;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

**ThreadData**

There is no need to call `super()` inside the constructor. You should remove it.

**LatestThread**

In the `getData()` method

- you are doing too many things. You should extract the manipulation of the `SplashScreen` to a separate method.
- you should add `finally` to close the `reader`.
- by reverting the `if` condition and using `continue` you can save horizontal space which makes your code more readable.
- if you are using java 1.7 or above you can use the diamond operator like `List<ThreadData> out = new ArrayList<>();`.
- implementing the mentioned points above leads to

  ```
  public List<ThreadData> getData() {
      List<ThreadData> out = new ArrayList<>();
      BufferedReader reader = null;
      try {
          URL url = new URL(WEBSITE_URL);
          reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
          String inputLine;
          int count = 0;
          while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null && count < THREADINDEX) {
              ThreadData in = getDetails(inputLine);
              if (in == null) {
                  continue;
              }

              out.add(in);
              count++;
              incrementProgressbar(33);
          }
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } finally {
          if (reader != null) {
              reader.close();
          }
      }

      return out;
  }

  private void incrementProgressbar(int value) {
      this.splash.getProgressBar().setValue(this.splash.getProgressBar().getValue() + value);
      this.splash.getDescLbl().setText("Loading News Data.");
      this.splash.repaint();
      this.splash.validate();
  }
  ```

In the `getContent()` method

- you should add  `finally` to close the `reader`.
- you should fix the indention of the code
- you are returning only the manipulated last match of the last line of the stream. If you wanted to do this, you should add a comment because it is not obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Patterns should be pre-compiled and held as a static field to avoid recompilation.

Using reluctant qualifiers we can match only up until the first closing tag.

```
private final static String REGEX_THREAD_CONTENT ="<div class=\"blizzquote\">(.*?)</div>";
private final static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX_THREAD_CONTENT);


Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputLine);
while (matcher.find()) {
    output = matcher.group(1);
}
```

Comment: Okay thank you both a lot, however I no longer need the blizzquote element and I'm attempting to pull the first posts in a certain news section, prior this was the method used for Vbulletin forums, I'm not exactly aiming to rewrite the code completely, but I am lost on figuring out how to do this on Invision power board, if anyone has any experience with IPB that would be awesome as I am only learning